# Trouble Automating PY Script From Flask Server

Tags: python, automation, flask

I'm trying to automate the running of a script. Unfortunately, when I deploy to Heroku, my script doesn't run. I have attached the code for my server. 'newsAgg' is a reference to my script.

Can anyone clear up why my script file is not run when deployed? (It works locally)

```
from flask import Flask
import newsAgg as N
import threading
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

def set_interval(func, sec):
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec)
        func()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t

newsInterval = set_interval(N.init, 3600)
N.init()
newsInterval()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: Are all the dependencies met? You might have newsAgg and/or even Flask installed locally but not in your remote server.